# Could running dpkg --configure -a cause packages to need an update?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

After a server (16.04 running headless) reboot, I ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to update packages. The second command printed:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

After that command I ran the first two commands and it printed out a massive block of text with `2054 upgraded, 550 newly installed, 66 to remove and 5 not upgraded.` I didn't continue because I didn't want to break anything.

I don't see anything unusual in my PPAs, is this expected behavior?

Edit: The output of `sudo apt update` as requested:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                               
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]             
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [49.0 kB]
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [59.7 kB]        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,877 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main i386 Packages [1,214 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [294 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [1,714 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe i386 Packages [1,560 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [289 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,288 B]
Fetched 7,323 kB in 4s (1,502 kB/s)                             

(appstreamcli:4546): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strchug: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:4546): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strchomp: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:4546): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strchug: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:4546): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strchomp: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:4546): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strchug: assertion 'string != NULL' failed

(appstreamcli:4546): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_strchomp: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
AppStream cache update completed, but some metadata was ignored due to errors.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
2067 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

Comment: That is expected behavior for `dist-upgrade` if you have recently changed your sources. That doesn't mean you should agree to the changes. It means you should investigate and fix your sources. It also means you should back up your data in case you need to reinstall.

Comment: @user535733 why would the sources have changed? I've had to manually comb through updates before, but never at this scale

Comment: You would be telling us about changed sources, since you are the one who would have changed them. Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1313965/edit) to show us the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: @user535733 Edited

Comment: Your output suggests that your sources have indeed changed. You have 18.04 (bionic) sources instead of 16.04 (xenial) sources. Therefore, the large number of changes suggested by `dist-upgrade` is appropriate. Obviously, you should back up your data first, since it seems like you may not have intended to release-upgrade.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you! I restored the `sources.list` file from a backup and it shows all packages are up to date. Now to figure out why they changed...

Comment: Get the installed version informations : `/usr/bin/lsb_release -a`, then check your `sources.list`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` was updated for 18.04. I had a backup of the file, so I was able to copy that over and resolve the issue.

If I didn't have a backup I would have had to replace all occurrences of `bionic` with `xenial`.